# Facebook Login on LoginActivity and secondtime facebook login on Invite page which is fragment

Tags: android, facebook, android-fragments, authentication, oauth

i'm developing App. in that Login with Facebook is used.On Main Login Screen(which is Activity) its working properly. But now i have to Login with Facebook option on other Fragment (i.e For Invite fragment, if user is not login with facebook then user can login from there).

Please Help me.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: you have to check the login status of fb through - `token = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();` if token is null then show the fb login button

Comment: @rushankshah shah, yes i can know  whether user is login with facebook or not but on fragment how to handle callback As per Facebook Doc we have to define class on which  we have to display fb Login Button.

Comment: You can define `onActivityResult` in your fragment class .
also write   `login_button.setFragment(this);` after `login_button = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);`  I have used fb login within fragment class.